# Newtonsoft on Mono 4.0

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to execute a compiled application on Ubuntu and get this error:

```
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /root/Newtonsoft.Json.dll mtoken: 0x0a000077
    Missing method System.Reflection.MethodInfo::CreateDelegate(Type) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /root/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
    Method not found: 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate'.  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetDefaultCreator (System.Type createdType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateLinqContract (System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract (System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.GetContractSafe (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal (System.Object value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Server.Misc.BalanceEconomy.InvokeMethod (System.String a_sMethod, System.Object[] a_params) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Server.Misc.BalanceEconomy.RefreshBalances () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Server.Misc.BalanceEconomy.OnTick () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: That method (MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(Type)) exists only on .NET Framework 4.5. Your JSON library has been compiled against that version.

Comment: mono 4.0 doesn't exist yet

Comment: (tell us the correct version of mono that you're using)